# Facebook API friends ids access on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I’m facing issues with **Facebook API** trying to implement a social app that accesses **all friends** from a user’s FB profile to be **selectively marked** (a bool flag) and synchronized with a backend so these marks remain until the friends have installed the app. The unique way to identify the friends is to use their **FB ids**, but as far as I read FB docs, they have strongly restricted their API starting with v2.0. **Real FB ids** are accessible only with `friends` request and it returns only friends that installed the app. I need all the friends in my app, so I tried to use `invitable_friends` and `taggable_friends` requests but they return only **temporal ids** for special usage such as invitation or tagging users. I also tried iOS FB Contact synchronization to extract ids, but not all friends are synchronized this way, only a few who attached special info to their profile.

My question is there a way to obtain **real FB ids** of all friends on iOS, so I’m able to identify them uniquely on the backend?

Comment: What do you need all friends for?

Comment: For saving their selected/unselected status on the backend before they've installed the app.

Answer (score 1):

For what you want to achieve, there is no way anymore to get ALL friends, i am afraid. `invitable_friends` is for inviting friends only, `taggable_friends` is for tagging friends only.

Btw, you don´t even get "real" IDs of the friends who authorized your App already, those are only "App Scoped IDs", only available in that App.

It does not really matter though, because you can always call `/me/friends` again and see if another friend authorized your App already. You can also update the list for those other friends then.

Comment: How do you think will it be appropriate to identify a user by their name that taggable_friends returns? Only a few users change such profile info on FB, so it can be considered as the permanent field.

Comment: you shouldn´t identify a user with taggable_friends - you would never get it approved for that anyway (taggable_friends has to go through the review process). you should only identify users after they authorized your app.